# CakePHP belongsTo not working

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a couple of tables in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `team_players` (
  `artificialid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `team_name_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `player_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`artificialid`)
)
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `team_names` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

And I have set up my TeamPlayer model like this:

```
class TeamPlayerModel extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'TeamName',
        'Player'
        )
    );
}
```

The players table has a field `id`, but neither of the associations are working.

I don't really understand why it isn't working, I have something like this working in another app, pretty much line for line.

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate any help.

Comment: you should use `TeamPlayer` instead of `Player`

Comment: Sorry, where exactly should I change this? The `Player` in the model association refers to another table.

Comment: It's not working, when I do `$teamPlayers = $this->TeamPlayer->find('all');` I'm getting something like this:

`(int) 4146 => array(
  'TeamPlayer' => array(
   'artificialid' => '4147',
   'team_name_id' => '1823',
   'player_id' => '211547'
  )
 ),`

Comment: what's the recursive level ? try this `$teamPlayers = $this->TeamPlayer->find('all', array('recursive' => 2))`

Comment: I did just have it at the default but even specifying it is not doing anything.

Comment: change artificialid to id - that is a Cake naming convention

Comment: Yeah I know, but I'm not trying to link to the id, I'm trying to link FROM the team_players table to the team_names table. Surely you shouldn't need to just have a field called 'id' for that to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to setup your model:

TeamPlayer.php:

```
class TeamPlayer extends AppModel {
   public $hasMany = array(

      'PlayerName'
     )
   ) ;
 }
```

TeamName.php:

```
class TeamName extends AppModel {
   public $belognsTo = array(

      'TeamPlayer'
     )
   ) ;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this too and I'm still getting no linked results when I debug the arrays that have been returned.